# How to make Visual Studio 2019 not breake inside a try statement when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I got a new computer, copied over some websites that I have built (asp.net vb), and downloaded VS 2019.  When I debug my websites VS will break on an exception that I have in a try statement and my other computer with an older version of VS does not do this (which is what I would like for this new setup).  I have made sure that "Enable Just My Code" is checked as I saw where that was a problem for some people.  Any ideas on how to make it stop would be helpful.  Thank you, Mark

Below is an example of the section of code that I was wanting it not to break on:

```
    Try
        bAppointmentBooked = Boolean.Parse(Session("AppointmentBooked").ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        bAppointmentBooked = False
    End Try
```

Comment: Turn off first-chance exceptions for those you do *not* want the debugger to break on when thrown, see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/) for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this article can be useful for you:
[Manage exceptions with the debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)

you must have some differences between VS2019 config and whatever other version you had.

Comment: That helped me figure it out (compaired Exception Settings from old computer - should have thought about that), I had to uncheck System.NullReferenceException under Common Language Runtime Exceptions in the Exception Settings, Thanks!